# Font-face mixin properties matching

Tags: css, sass, font-face

Should I change the `font-style` or `font-weight` property in this situation?

```
@font-face 
    font-family: $fontLight
    font-style: normal
    font-weight: normal
    src: url('/fonts/#{$fontLight}.eot')
    src: url('/fonts/#{$fontLight}.eot?') format('eot'),
    src: url('/fonts/#{$fontLight}.woff') format('woff'),
    src: url('/fonts/#{$fontLight}.ttf')  format('truetype')
```

Comment: If you want to use different font files for different styles/weights...

Comment: I mean, in this case, should I change font-style: from normal to light? Or this is not even necessary since the shapes are light glyphs

Comment: If this is a mixin for light fonts, then it would probably make sense to change the font-weight.